# Is it possible to consume marijuana within Denver International Airport?

Tags: legal, international-travel, smoking, den

DEN (Denver International Airport) in Colorado, USA, has a number of smoking lounges, something I've never seen in any other airport anywhere else in the United States.

Since the possession and consumption of marijuana for personal purposes is no longer forbidden by Colorado law, can you smoke marijuana in the airport whilst waiting for your connecting flight?

Answer (score 13):

No, it is not the case.

According to a DEN employee in 2014, the airport falls under the federal jurisdiction, and the federal government does not allow such sales to take place. Thus, all smoking lounges in DEN are cannabis-free.

Apparently, according to the same employee, some people do manage to get past the security and into those lounges with their own legally-purchased pot, but, the lounge attendants have a directive to not allow the guests to keep at it, either.

Comment: Interesting, are all US airports under federal jurisdiction or just DEN ?

Comment: @Blackbird57 They are not under exclusive federal jurisdiction like Washington DC is under federal jurisdiction; but the matter is nuanced. The State (or in this case the City of Denver) owns the airport and has power to make laws or regulations on it as usual. For instance in Atlanta one can open carry a loaded weapon around the airport: http://www.wsbtv.com/news/news/local/man-raises-eyebrows-carrying-gun-through-atlanta-a/nmTFS/ But the Congress imposes some constraints on the airside part of the airport, see https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/49/44903#c

Comment: In addition, while marijuana use is legal in Colorado, public smoking of marijuana is not.

Comment: You say the federal government doesn't allow the _sale_ of marijuana, but what does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 7):

No, you may not.

Denver City Council passed an ordinance banning the possession of marijuana within Denver International Airport. It is an offense punishable by fine or imprisonment, although it seems to be laxly enforced.

http://www.denverpost.com/marijuana/ci_24813887/dia-first-denver-facility-ban-marijuana-possession

http://www.usatoday.com/story/todayinthesky/2014/02/06/carry-on-weed-a-security-riddle-at-colo-wash-airports/5245917/

Answer (score 3):

No, you will not be able to consume marijuana in any airport. I would recommend consuming your cannabis that you purchased in a dispensary before you enter the airport. It will make the flight more interesting.

Marijuana is still illegal under federal law because it is still on the Schedule 1 Controlled Substance list. Airport security abides by federal law. You may risk getting the airport cops on you and missing your flight. Not advisable!